# How to perform carrier doping (hole/electron) for 2D materials by Quantum Espresso?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, electronic-structure, phonons, 2d-lattice

I tried to set the `tot_charge` parameter of Quantum Espresso to alter the charge of the system, but the phonon spectrum I obtained was very strange. Could anyone give me any advice on using Quantum Espresso to calculate carrier doping?

Comment: Please could you provide a little more information and background? What did you set the charge to, and how many atoms are there in your unit cell? What was strange about the phonon spectrum? I'm also curious why you're calculating phonon DOS after doping.

Comment: I want to study the effect of carrier doping on the superconductivity of 2D materials. Therefore, I try to replicate a work ( https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.00105 ). In this paper, the authors used hole doping and biaxial strain to induce superconductivity of hydrogenated monolayer hexagonal boron nitride. I calculated the phonon frequency of Gamma point with hole doping (FIG. 4) using roughly the same parameters, but the results were quite different. The highest frequency in the paper is about 1200cm-1, but I calculated it to be about 3000cm-1.Thanks for your attention @PhilHasnip

Comment: How similar is your computational method? Have you managed to reproduce their relaxed geometry and electronic properties?